# OleDB no lee la totalidad de filas de un archivo excel C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008-r2, oledb

Actualmente cuento con un proyecto que recorre un archivo excel .xlsx e inserta los registros en una base de datos SQL SERVER.

El problema es originado una vez que realizo el paso a producción, en equipo de desarrollo un archivo especifico con 14.476 registros es cargado sin problemas, sin embargo al ejecutar en producción el mismo archivo solo carga 11.123 registros.

El método utilizado es:

```cs
conn.ConnectionString = "provider =Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;data source = " + rutaDocumento + ";Persist Security Info=False;Extended Properties=&quot;Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;IMEX=1&quot;MaxScanRows=0;";
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM " + NombreHoja; $
cmd.Connection = conn;               
                
da.SelectCommand = cmd;
conn.Open();
da.Fill(ds);
```

Comment: Y estas seguro que es el mismo archivo? si el codigo esta bien, no tenemos mucho para hacer aca...

Answer (score -1):

un poco tarde pero aplicamos este referencia
http://www.mvp-access.es/softjaen/articulos/excel/ado_dao_excel.htm#Index3

El MaxScanRows  no lo pongas en 0

Comment: Si bien este enlace puede responder a la pregunta, es mejor incluir las partes esenciales de la respuesta aquí y proporcionar el enlace como referencia.  Las respuestas que son únicamente un enlace pueden dejar de ser válidas si la página vinculada cambia. - [Desde revisión](/review/late-answers/323702)